# Poco, child communication hangs (python interpreter is child)

Tags: python, c++, lua, poco-libraries

I want communicate with python & lua scripts, but python not working as expected. Python hangs:

Log:

```
lua << 'hello!',   lua >> 'hello!'
lua << 'hello!',   lua >> 'hello!'
lua << 'hello!',   lua >> 'hello!'
python << 'hello!',
```

Main C++ application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Process.h"
#include "Poco/PipeStream.h"
void test( char const* interpreter, char const* filename )
{
   std::vector<std::string> args { filename };
   Poco::Pipe outPipe;
   Poco::Pipe inPipe;
   Poco::ProcessHandle process_handle = Poco::Process::launch( interpreter, args, &inPipe, &outPipe , nullptr/*errPipe*/ );
   Poco::PipeInputStream output_reader(outPipe);
   Poco::PipeOutputStream input_writer(inPipe);
   for(int repeat_counter=0; repeat_counter<3; ++repeat_counter)
   {
      auto send_str("hello!");
      input_writer << send_str << std::endl;
      std::cout << interpreter << " << '" << send_str << "',   " );
      std::cout.flush();
      std::string receiv_str;
      output_reader >> receiv_str;
      std::cout << interpreter << " >> '" << receiv_str << "'" << std::endl;
   }
}
int main()
{
   test("lua","test.lua");
   test("python","test.py");
   return 0;
}
```

Lua script:

```
for i=1,10 do
   print(io.read())
end
```

Python script:

```
for i in range(0,10):
   print(raw_input())
```

**In Terminal both scripts works identically.**

Solution: For Python must use only **sys.stdout.write** & **flush**, Thanks @greatwolf

Comment: probably `raw_input()` waits for `"\n"` (Enter)

Comment: @furas, std::endl already sends "\n" & flush()

Comment: maybe python's `print` is doing something funny behind the scenes and not directly outputting to stdout? What about trying `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: @greatwolf, it is solution! Yo are great. Make answer.

Comment: There you go, glad to help :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that python's `print` function isn't directly outputting to stdout or there's some funny business happening behind the scenes. Try replacing it with `sys.stdout.write` instead. Don't forget to `import sys` first.